# How to include all markers on google maps BUT also always center to one of the coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift5

I have an app that is showing points of interest around the user and also the user's location. What I am struggling with is the following: How to include all the point of interest markers and also ALWAYS center the map around the user's marker.

I am aware of the method: 
`zoom(toInclude: [CLLocationCoordinate2D], animated: Bool)` ,
    but that method is missing the option to center the map around a specific marker / coordinates.

I have also tried setting up `GMSCoordinateBounds` to include all of my points of interests as well as `userLocation` and then calling `GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds)` to set the camera to include all of my markers, which basically achieves the same result as the `zoom(toInclude:)` function.

So I would like to always center a map around a specific location WHILE also zooming out to the point so that all of my POIs are included and displayed on the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `GMSMapView`'s camera to the coordinates you want to show in center.

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: UserLocation.coordinates.latitude, longitude: UserLocation.coordinates.longitude, zoom: 10.0)
self.mapView.animate(to: camera)
```

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't guarantee that the other markers will be included in the view